# TheOdinProject- Rock,Paper,Scissors- cannot loop the playRound function

Tags: javascript

Before I begin with the problem, let me just say I am new here and I know this question has been asks quite a few times, but It would be greatly appreciated if I could receive some feedback on my own write-up of the code for looping the **playRound** function in the code for rock, paper, scissors.

When checking if a result is returned using this;

```
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

a result is returned and I can say that the **playRound** and the **computerPlay** function works as I get a random return of three choices. However, when attempting to wrap the **playRound** function inside the **game** function nothing happens or I get two prompts after which an *uncaught TypeError: computerPlay is not a function* is returned on lines 19, 50, 53. If the variables are made parameters inside the **playRound** function as recommened by theODinProject, console.log returns an undifined, but no errors appear.

I have looked at other peoples code and recommendations on how to fix this problem in the code (It seems quite common). From looking at other's code, I have learned the way this is written is not, shall we say, the cleanest, or even good. I was also tempted to just imitate the other contributed results, but not only does that feel like cheating, I feel like I would learn less if I cannot at least fix this code to at least return the results of five games.

Code is as fallows;

```
     let input = prompt("what do you choose, rock, paper, or scissors?");
}
     
     //computer makes a move
     function computerPlay() {
     computerPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
     if (computerPlay === 0 ) {
      return "rock";
     } else if (computerPlay === 1) {
      return "paper";
     } else if (computerPlay === 2) {
      return "scissors";
     }
}
     
     function playRound() {
       const playerSelection = humanPlayer(); 
       const computerSelection = computerPlay();   
       //rock
     if(playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors"){
      return "Good job! You had a one in three chance to win and you did. Congratulations...";
     } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "rock") {
      return "Oh, Well. It could be worse. You Could of Chosen paper."
     } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") {
      return "AHAHAHA. You lost. Loser."
     }
       //paper
     else if(playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection == "rock"){
      return "Good job! You had a one in three chance to win and you did. Congratulations...";
     } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "paper") {
      return "Oh, Well. It could be worse. You Could of Chosen paper."
     } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
      return "AHAHAHA. You lost. Loser."
     }
       //scissors
     else if(playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
      return "Good job! You had a one in three chance to win and you did. Congratulations...";
     } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
      return "Oh, Well. It could be worse. You Could of Chosen paper."
     } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") {
      return "AHAHAHA. You lost. Loser."
     } else {
      return "Good-bye"
     }
}
     
     function game() {
     for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     playRound();
     }
 }
console.log(game())
```

I plan on refactoring it later. Or just scrapping the whole thing and starting over. My question is, why won't this code loop?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Don't do this: `function computerPlay() {
     computerPlay ` unless you intend to do a recursive call. You don't need to even use loops at all. Are you trying to simulate 5 rounds? You have to use another interface, prompt limits your options. Also, it's not cheating, everyone takes a little bit of code from another source, it's impossible to learn if you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance on the code peaking part. I'll look more into other options besides prompts as well.

Comment: Click on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813224/zer00ne) and in the search bar add (but don't overwrite) "rock paper scissors" (without quotes). I think I have a couple of roshambo answers. In fact I have a one line ternary that covers the outcome of a round in one them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: computerPlay is not a function` on the second iteration, it is because within the `computerPlay()` function you are overwriting the function definition. To solve it you can use a variable name different than the function name like:

```
function computerPlay() {
    let computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    if (computerSelection === 0 ) {
        return "rock";
    } else if (computerSelection === 1) {
        return "paper";
    } else if (computerSelection === 2) {
        return "scissors";
    }
}
```

*Also you should add `return input` at the end of the `humanPlayer()` function which I believe you posted the last part of.

```
function humanPlayer() {
    let input = prompt("what do you choose, rock, paper, or scissors?");
    return input;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That cleared the error right-up.  What an easy fix too (haha!